# Large images with overflow: hidden; don't get centered in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of the horizontal scroll bar (A) but when I changed my footer my images got messed up (B) and I'm not sure what is happening or what to do.

A: Unwanted horizontal scroll: https://mabonzo.github.io/prj-rev-bwfs-tea-cozy/teacozy/

B: Commented out footer and the images go wonky: https://mabonzo.github.io/prj-rev-bwfs-tea-cozy-test/teacozy/

Initially I was trying to change my footer rule-set from having `left: 20px;` to `margin-left: 20px;` or `padding-left: 20px;` when I ran into this problem! I speculate that it is related to the actual resolutions of the images, but I'm not sure.

Resizing the browser fixes centers the images.

I asked on a Slack group to no avail, I just tested it on different browsers and it seems like this is an issue only on Firefox. On Chrome and Edge they load no problem... So I guess my updated question is how to fix this for Firefox users.

EDIT: going to update the website, so the problem won't be in the (A) link. But the TEST site (B) will still be up and broken. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox might just render `position: absolute;` images within `display: flex; position: relative; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` divs weird!

I fixed the problem by adding the `align-self: flex-start;` and `top: 0;` declarations to the `.mission-child img` and `.locations-child img` rule-sets.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `footer` element has an `auto` width (which is the full width of the screen, because it's a block level element) but then you say `left: 20px` (combined with `position:relative`) so now it's the full width of the screen but it starts 20px from the left, meaning it will always be 20px off the right side of the screen.

`padding-left:20px` on the `footer` will accomplish the same goal and not cause the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Yes! That is what I was trying to change when I ran into my images breaking

Answer (score 0):

Your images seem to be defaulting to the left on Firefox because you have `position: absolute` on `.mission-child img`. Setting this to `position: relative` seems to correctly centralise the images for me.

Your footer occupies the full width on the page, in addition to having `left: 20px` on it. This **offsets** from the left, leading it to have a total width of `100% + 20px`. To offset the text contained within, but not the footer itself, you're looking for **`padding-left: 20px`**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I wanted to use an image instead of a background image, and using `position: absolute;` is the only way I thought it could be achieved. `position: relative;` moves the image above the text instead of being a mock background image

Comment: @Mabonzo - if you want to use it as a background image, then you should use CSS - `background-image`

Comment: @Adam I like using `background-image: url(""); background-size: cover;` but the point of the images (for me) wasn't for a background, and I like to add `alt` attributes to images with significance (maybe this is a bad practice for backgrounds?) AND I wanted to challenge myself because I am learning. Thank you though!